# What's the difference between using flatMap and combine a list of flows?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-flow-flatmaplatest

I have been writing some handling for my flows interchangeably in my codebase, especially in my Usecases and repositories. I would like to get some insight into what would be the better approach, and why, between the two solutions below. What I am looking for in the end is to go from `Flow<List<ItemInfo>>` to `Flow<List<Item>>` where any changes to the Item in the ItemRepo will update the flow - i.e it uses a function call that returns `Flow<Item>`.

Repository functions:

```kotlin
InfoRepo.homeItems() : Flow<List<ItemInfo>>
ItemRepo.getItem(info: ItemInfo): Flow<Item>
```

On my home screen, I want to display all items available so in my use case I can do either:

```kotlin
infoRepo.homeItems().flatMapLatest { homeList ->
    val listOfFlows = homeList.map { itemRepo.getItem(it) } // List<Flow<Item>>
    combine (listOfFlows) { array -> array.toList() } // assumes list never empty
}
```

OR

```kotlin
infoRepo.homeItems().map { homeList ->
    homeList.asFlow().flatMapConcat { bulletRepo.observeBullet(it) }.toList()
}
```

I have a utility function `List<Flow<T>>.combineToList(): Flow<List<T>>` that does the `combine(list){ it.toList() }` for me.

Which of these two are more performant, less error prone and works as mostly expected? Or is it just flavour, is it neither?

Comment: Question: Why use `Flow<List<ItemInfo>>`? Will you get more lists? Why not better `Flow<ItemInfo>`?

Comment: I only want to consume the ItemInfo as a list. I want to present a list of items, not present an update of a single item

Comment: I can not see details, but I would use `suspend fun homeItem(): List<ItemInfo>` and not need Flow if this flow contains only one element. If it contains more, you will get a semantic problem because you use only the latest, not all.

Comment: suspend is not good enough in this case as I am observing and receiving updates with a new list of any of the items changes - that's the whole idea

Comment: If this is backed by a database, you should use a query that directly returns the `Flow<List<ItemInfo>>` which you can simply `map` to `Flow<List<Item>>`. Then you won't be running tons of parallel queries over and over.

Comment: All comments are avoiding the question, or trying to find solutions to something else. I have a flow that holds a list, based in the items in that lists I need to fetch other items, each requires it's own flow (from room, Android) and in the end return everything combined as a single list of items in a list, on a flow. It's all in the question above, don't question the intention, please.